# .htaccess rewrite rule to append the date to the filename, using Content-Disposition header

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to download different file types like PDF, XLS, .jpg, .png, etc. directly from Joomla CMS via web browser. Documents and files like Word, Excel, Powerpoint, PDFs, .jpg, .png and text are stored in Joomla DOCman and when a user wants a file they click a link in DOCman menu in the website and the file is getting downloaded. I would like to get the date appended to the file name, when users download files like PDF, XLS, .jpg, .png, etc. from the website menu created. It loos like this is possible at server level using a htaccess rewrite rule, as the filename the browsers uses to save a file is included in the Content-Disposition header:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Is it possible to rewrite that header to append the date to the downloaded filename? I tried the below code in htaccess file for PDF file type, but it doesn't work as expected.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule [^/]+\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$0]
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
    Header set Content-Disposition "attachment; filename=%{FILENAME-.date('Y-m-d').}e" 
</FilesMatch>
```

Any help to get the correct htaccess rewrite rule to accomplish the above, would be higly appreciated.

Comment: No, you can _not_ use PHP code (`date('Y-m-d')`) in .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks, is there any other options available to append the date to downloaded file names using .htaccess/Content-Disposition header?

Comment: You could try and use the date- and time variables Apache provides, https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html#vars

Comment: I tried using the Apache variable "%{TIME_DAY}" also in the above htaccess rewrite rule, with no luck :(

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. This was tested and works.

```bash
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
<FilesMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
    Header onsuccess set Content-Disposition "expr=attachment; filename=\"%{ENV:FILENAME}-%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}\.pdf\"" env=FILENAME
</FilesMatch>
```

The Apache documentation for the [Header directive](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header) shows that the `%{VARNAME}e` format specifier should be used for placing environment variables in the Header value. However, since the value is provided via an *ap_expr* expression in my code sample, the [ap_expr function](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#functions) **env** (or maybe *reqenv*) should be used instead. The Header directive documentation says that within *ap_expr* expressions:

> Function calls use the %{funcname:arg} syntax rather than funcname(arg).

Comment: Thank you! I have tried the above code provided in .htaccess and it shows the 500 internal server error in browser. The Apache error logs indicate the following

"

/var/www/html/.htaccess: Unrecognized header format %-

"

Can you advise? I am running Apache version 2.4.6 on CentOS 7.6.

Comment: Could be related to the escape characters. Try removing the two escaped double quotes: **\"** (replace with nothing). Also, remove the **\.** (replace with just the dot).

Comment: I tried removing the escaped double quotes as you suggested, but still getting the same error :( ` /var/www/html/.htaccess: Unrecognized header format %- ` , below is the updated code. 

`
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$1]
<FilesMatch ".(?i:pdf)$">
    Header set Content-Type application/octet-stream
    Header onsuccess set Content-Disposition "expr=attachment; filename=%{ENV:FILENAME}-%{TIME_YEAR}-%{TIME_MON}-%{TIME_DAY}.pdf" env=FILENAME
</FilesMatch>
`
any help will be appreciated!

Comment: I was only able to reproduce the error by removing the **expr=** prefix from the expression.
You could try removing terms from the expression one-by-one to see which ones are accepted without error, and which ones cause the error. From the error message, it looks like at least one of those terms is being rejected, causing an empty string to be returned which results in **%-**. If you find the rejected term, post it in a comment and we can try to find a version that works for you. Since the escaped double quotes aren't the problem, you could re-include them back into the expression.

Comment: Thank you for the continued help.. None of the % inside the expr= prefix is working and the site shows internal server error then. when I take out % completely from the expression, the errors like Unrecognized header format %- , %% and %\\ disappear. % is common in all the errors and looks like it's not working inside the expression. Do you know whether it has any issues with the Apache version 2.4.6?

Comment: "I am running Apache version 2.4.6" - As per the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html#header), `expr=value` (Apache expressions) are only available in 2.4.10 and later. However, you should be able to assign these values to env vars (as you are already doing for the _filename_) and use the standard `%{VARNAME}e` syntax as mentioned above (or use the server variable directly)? You don't _need_ to use an _ap_expr_ here. @SriV

Comment: I have upgraded Apache to latest 2.4.54 and the above provided code is not throwing internal server error or Unrecognized header format % now. Looks like it was related to the older Apache version 2.4.6. However, the files from Joomla DOCman menu are still getting downloaded without the time/date appended to them, with this rewrite rule in .htaccess file :(

Comment: @MrWhite thanks for finding the issue with the version.
For reference:
I am running Apache/2.4.16 (Win64).
When I tried to use `%{VARNAME}e` without ap_expr, Apache reports the error `Unrecognized header format %-`.

@Sri I wonder if what you're dealing with now is how Joomla's DOCman handles files. I'm not familiar with Joomla DOCman. Would your Apache logs give you a clue about what requests are being made? Maybe adding `L` to the Rewrite Rule flag might change something. The rule could be updated to: `RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.pdf$ - [E=FILENAME:$1,L]`.

Comment: Since your web site is managed by Joomla/DOCman, that means they could be the final step before the response is sent back to the browser. They could be using PHP code like this:
```php
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="$filename.pdf"');
echo $file;
```
to return the file to the browser. The Apache Header directive would then be overwritten by PHP (which explains why .htaccess is ineffective). Rather than using .htaccess you might have to modify Joomla or DOCman itself if they don't provide options within their administration/configuration interfaces.

Comment: So, while it is possible in general to re-write the file name to include the date, if we consider the implications of Joomla and DOCman maybe I should update my answer to say "_No, what you want to do is not possible using .htaccess._".

Comment: Thank you @kofeigen for all the help! I will check further with the DOCman team regarding this.